# Batch Opening Multiple Revit Model - Dismiss BIM360 Sign In

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a question about opening Multiple Revit Model in background to perform some batch automation task. These models were downloaded from BIM360 Design collaboration and placed into a folder.

```
public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
        Document rvtDoc = null;
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Models", "*.rvt");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            ModelPath modelPath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertUserVisiblePathToModelPath(Path.GetFileName(file));
            if (modelPath != null)
            {
                OpenOptions openOptions = new OpenOptions();
                WorksetConfiguration openConfiguration = new WorksetConfiguration(WorksetConfigurationOption.OpenAllWorksets);
                openOptions.SetOpenWorksetsConfiguration(openConfiguration);
                openOptions.DetachFromCentralOption = DetachFromCentralOption.ClearTransmittedSaveAsNewCentral;
                openOptions.Audit = false;

                var currentDoc = uiapp.OpenAndActivateDocument(modelPath, openOptions, false);


            }
        }
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
```

I couldn't skip the Login screen as shown in below images.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to open and activate the document by?

*var currentDoc = uiapp.OpenAndActivateDocument(modelPath, openOptions, false);*

How about using the following way:

*var currentDoc = uiapp.Application.OpenDocumentFile(modelPath, openOptions);*

Comment: I have tried both ways it's not working. Infact I'm trying to UnloadAll Revit Links from the model before opening however there seems to be error and I couldn't figured out how to unload links which has the BIM360 path.

Comment: What exactly error do you see if using Application.OpenDocumentFile(modelPath, openOptions) ?